# Specify per node route if authentication is needed or not

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, token, json-web-token

I m building a node web service. This contains multiple routes.
Some of them need authentication, others not.
I use json-web-token to create and verify tokens, that work, as long as I am happy with the following:

```
router
    // main routes
    .get('/', main.catchAll)
    .post('/register', main.register)
    .post('/authenticate', main.authenticate)
    .use(main.verifyToken)
    .get('/years', main.years)
    // game routes
    .get('/games', game.newestGames)
    .get('/game/title/:id', game.gameName)
    .get('/game/:id', game.gameDetails)
    .get('/genres', genres.genres)
```

This results in all routes that are defined after the `.use(...)` will need authentication.
However, to keep track of all my routes I want to group them per category, but that means I am not able to use the verification as I am used to.

For example: I don't want the `.get('/games', game.newestGames)` to need authentication

Is there a way to specify per route that it needs verification or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can either do:

```
app.use('/years', main.varifyToken, main.years)
```

Or if you want to make it only on some verbs:

```
app.get('/years', main.years)
app.post('/years', main.verifyToken, main.postYears)
```

You can also look into using Routers to group functionality and auth.  I find it easier to make sense of my routes when I do